# JS floating message box with fade

Tags: javascript

(I'm not sure what is it call!)
For example you enter a website, you see a the left there is a button with an arrow ( <- ), sroll with you, and when you click in a box expand, when you click agian the box close.

PLeas tell me what is it and where I can find some demo code :D
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what it's typically called, but I Googled around and eventually came up with: ["side slide in hidden with jquery"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=side+slide+in+hidden+with+jquery&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=).  It's a bit unwieldy, but it got results, and [here's a jQuery plugin](http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html) to do it.  You might try some more searching to find something that could fit your needs better.

In addition, [here's a jQuery plugin](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/jScroll/) to keep elements on the page when you scroll, although I've seen better (Where they update more frequently.  It's a tradeoff between browser load - with many javascript updates - and snappiness).  Try [Googling "scoll div with page jQuery"](http://www.google.com/search?q=scroll+div+with+page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=yQD&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=scroll+div+with+page+jquery&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f17ae772ca1ea813&biw=1680&bih=890) to find other results.

Comment: Thanks you rockerest the link https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=side+slide+in+hidden+with+jquery&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq= is what I need! Thanks you agian!